# Joomla and blog.php

Tags: templates, joomla3.0, overwrite

it seams i look around all the file in

templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/category/blog.php

I could find there, how to edit category blog title and some other things too. But the most important thing i couldn't find, where can i edit article title, image, text. and make them to look as I want.

where it should be title, image and text i could find only a php code

```
$this->item = & $item;
echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
```

If anyone can guide me, which file i have to edit, to make my title of an article, image and text look as i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the override, find the code in:
your_template/html/com_content/category/**blog_item.php**

- Code for title in category blog:

```html
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.blog_style_default_item_title', $this->item); ?>
```

- Code for Intro image in category blog:

```html
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

Comment: Thank You I found everything that i need :)